# A 2nd countable metric space is separable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> A 2nd countable metric space is separable

Can anyone give an idea on how to prove that, I could prove the converse quite easily but I am not sure which set to consider in order to show that it is dense.

Comment: Regarding the converse: there are spaces that are separable but not second countable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology for example.

Comment: @Shane: But these are not metrizable spaces.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, indeed. I somehow managed not to see the word `metric' in my haste.

Answer (score 7):

HINT: Start with a countable base $\mathscr{B}$ for the topology and pick one point from each member of $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a way of defining the set which is set up by picking one point from each member please?

Comment: @user68099: Just do this: for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ let $x_B\in B$, and let $D=\{x_B:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$. Because $\mathscr{B}$ is countable, $D$ must also be countable, and it’s easy to see that it’s dense. You really can’t hope to be any more specific than that about the nature of $D$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and then $ D $ is dense and countable

Comment: @user68099: That’s right. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry. As you only asked for a hint, I now hide my answer in the following spoiler box:

> Let $(U_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis of nonempty sets for the 2nd countable metrik space $(X,d)$. Fix a choice function $f: \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n \mapsto V$, where $V$ is the universal class. We claim that the set $(f(U_n))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is dense. In fact, for any open $U \subseteq X$ there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_{n_0} \subseteq U$ (by definition of a basis) and thus $f(U_{n_0}) \in U$, showing density.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the axiom of choice, you can't always write an explicit countable dense subset.

**Hint:** Use the fact that you have a countable basis to the topology, and those sets are all non-empty.

Comment: Lana, yes. I am well aware of that. Many beginners try to do things by writing them explicitly. Pointing out the necessity of AC is important because it may explain difficulties that occurred when trying to work out the proof.

Comment: Is it useful to point out set theoretic details instead of going to the heart of the proof each times (no offense man, just asking your opinion)? In topology AC is quite an obvious assumption, otherwise you'd lose its most important theorems as you surely know

Answer (score 1):

The metric assumption is really useless, it works in every second countable topological space: pick an element from each open basic set (using AC) and collect them in a set. This countable set is dense in the original topological space.

Comment: Perhaps the unnecessary assumption "metric" is there because the problem was originally to prove the equivalence between "second countable" and "separable".  The OP mentions being able to prove the converse, which needs metrizability (and doesn't need AC!), and  (s)he might have simply retained that hypothesis for the remaining direction.

Comment: Yes the question was to prove that any metric spaces is seperable iff its second countable, and hence had to necessarily consider only metric spaces

Comment: ..but not for this side of the equivalence!